# Docker image running as unknown user ID can delete root files

Tags: linux, security, docker, debian, file-permissions

Is this correct? A random user ID can delete a file owned by root?

`docker run -ti -u 1001 debian:stretch
I have no name!@2af53be18a40:/$ rm -f /etc/passwd
I have no name!@2af53be18a40:/$ ls /etc/passwd
ls: cannot access '/etc/passwd': No such file or directory`

I think this used to work (i.e. permission denied), although I haven't tried that exact sequence of commands in the past. The results above are from `Docker version 1.12.2, build bb80604` running on Stretch.

Comment: Oddly, I can't replicate this behavior myself; running the same set of commands locally results in `rm: cannot remove '/etc/passwd': Permission denied`.

Comment: May depend on Docker version; I've updated the question.

Comment: This is off-topic here I'm afraid, but deleting a file modifies the directory, not the file, so whether you can delete it depends on ownership and access rights of the directory that contains the file, and not the file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy to report that this is fixed in Docker 1.23!